# Scale application differently on different monitors - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, nvidia-settings

I have found a lot of very solid articles/answers about this topic:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/555812/574648
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/213984
- https://askubuntu.com/a/662567/574648

And of course:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays

However, I'm still struggling. My laptop is Dell XPS15. Its display is 3840x2160. I have tried different external monitors, but at the moment the one I use is also Dell with resolution 1920x1080.

When I connect external monitor, some of the panels immediately become very small on 3840x2160 screen. When I try to scale up build-in display, chrome scales, my IDE scales, but displays window along with other windows like NVIDIA X Server settings stay very small. I have tried to play with **Scale all window contents to match** in **Display** but to no avail. It's either too big on the external screen or to small on the build-in.
I have also tried xrandr with scale param but it gives me:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --scale 2x2
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
  Value in failed request:  0x40
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
```

**Ideally, I want several windows of the same application(let's say Chrome or Intellij Idea to be open on different displays and scale independently on them).**

#### EDIT

I am not looking for **Scale for menus and title bar**, I like the way the bars are. I want windows contents scaled independently. **Displays** UI forces me to either scale all windows to match Built-id display or the external display. As a result:

1. *Scale all window contents to match* Build-In Display:

   Build-In Display - everything looks perfect;
   External Display - everything is huge.
2. *Scale all window contents to match* External Display:

   Build-In Display - very small;
   External Display - everything looks perfect.

Comment: You missed the AskUbuntu link that had 100 bounty on the answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/823529/how-do-you-set-scaling-for-a-high-dpi-monitor-and-low-dpi-monitor-independently/823535#823535

Comment: Kindly visit the link in my previous comment, review it and add it to your list of links you've visited. Also write a short summary of how it does or doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, while I see a question in your link very similar, I don't see a helpful answer there. In fact, I don't even find anything to try, it's all totally irrelevant. I'm not looking for changing overall DPI value. I need a solution for 2 monitors with different resolutions.

Comment: you need to scroll down to the accepted answer that won the 100 bounty. If that answer doesn't solve your issues then I'll develop a solution for different DPI's (say 144 and 168) on two separate monitors (say 55" TV and 17" laptop) which you can adapt to your situation. It will be tonight though as I'm preparing to go out shopping soon.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I've seen both answers. How is that bounty answer different from what I provided in the first place. I've already spent a lot of time playing with --scale. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I actually don't have the problem that link had and you have. I was hoping the accepted answer there solved all your problem. Since it does not I'll invest some time tonight writing an answer which I hope solves your problem. I wanted to tweak the DPI on my TV differently than my Laptop anyway but, it was a low priority project. Now you've given me reason to bump it up the priority list :). Check back in around 6-9 hours.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I would immeasurably appreciate your effort! Check my edit. I provided an example to make it more clear.

Comment: I'm getting bogged down with pixel calculator: http://pxcalc.com/ referenced by this DPI setup article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xorg#Display_size_and_DPI and  this multi-monitor setup article: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multihead I think you might be able to figure this out faster than me.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thanks for the links, but they are for the most part about coordinates and DPIs. I don't have any problem with either of those. What I need is scaling. Even when DPI is recognised correctly, there can be a problem with windows sizes when monitors with very different resolutions are used simultaneously.

Comment: Could you update your question with the output from `xrandr --listmonitors` please?

Comment: I have exactly the same laptop (Dell XPS 15 ) and the same usage (IntelliJ, Chrome,  ... ) and obviously  the same problem.

I would really an answer to this question, so let me offer a bounty on this.

The output of `xrandr -listmonitors ` is this 
```
 ❯ xrandr --listmonitors                                                                                                               
Monitors: 2
 0: +*eDP-1-1 3840/346x2160/194+0+0  eDP-1-1
 1: +HDMI-1-1 1920/527x1080/296+3840+0  HDMI-1-1
```

Comment: @systho, Could you add an update to the question , add the output of `sudo apt-get install pastebinit; sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; lshw -c display; echo ==; xrandr --verbose; echo ==; cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf" | tee ~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt | pastebinit`

Comment: @systho, try using single command, may be xrandr modify previous monitor setup when it is run on two steps example: `xrandr --output VGA-0 --scale 2x2 --mode 1440x900 --fb 2880x2600 --pos 0x800 --output DP-3 --mode 1280x800 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0` , yours could be: `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080 --fb 7680x2160 --pos 3840x0 --output eDP-1-1 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0`

Comment: @user.dz
Hi sorry for the delay, the bounty has cost me so much rep that I could not comment again...

Here is the output you asked (it's quite long)

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ca481fb78d3b61502ce7b69e37edaff

Comment: @user.dz Any attempt to use `scale` in `xrandr`  generate the same error, even `1x1`

`xrandr --output eDP-1-1 --scale 1x1`

`                                                                                                       
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  26 (RRSetCrtcTransform)
  Value in failed request:  0x3f
  Serial number of failed request:  38
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
`

Comment: @user.dz I'm currently using nvidia drivers 375.26

Comment: @systho, I will undelete my previous answer and update it even some methods did not work for me or you, it may work for others or may lead us to better solution.

Comment: @systho, updated my answer also found a trick to make nvidia-settings works. Please, logout/login before trying each method.  drivers/xrandr too buggy, many weird behaviors I can't explain.

Comment: i have the same screen in my laptop (dell precision m3800) , if i am using my external 40inch 4k screen i set the laptop to be 1920x1080 and its the same scale as the screen.  I've not got it to work with the scale reliably.

Answer (score 3):

I have nvidia driver `340.98` with GT218M [NVS 3100M], Xubuntu 16.04, any results below are from this environment if I don't mention otherwise. Here is [my testing environment info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23738679/), the output of:

```
sudo apt-get install pastebinit; \
sudo sh -c "lsb_release -sd; \
 dmidecode -s system-product-name; echo ==; \
 lshw -c display; echo ==; \
 xrandr --verbose; echo ==; \
 cat /etx/X11/xorg.conf" \
 | tee ~/Desktop/ubuntu-graphic-info.txt \
 | pastebinit
```

Weird and complex stack to debug specially using proprietary drivers. Most of the time, I get unexpected behaviors, may be due to lack of knowledge about the current Linux graphics stack setup.

- I wrote [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/727897/26246) before, that may introduce some debugging tools like `xtrace`
- Avoid running multiple/sequential `xrandr` commands, only after X server reset. Same command may have different result depending on previous commands. I have noticed that with `--scale` (see test case from my answer, linked above) `--transform` & `--fb`. Still don't know an easy way only by logout/login. So always logout/login before making another trial.
- Screenshots take only pixel size image from FB, so I will add camera photos to show the real results.

### Method 1: `xrandr --output .. --scale HCoefxVCoef` or `--scale-from WxH`

*Note, works fine for me. `--scale` is a shortcut for `--transform`, see method3*

(VGA-0 below DP-3)

```
xrandr \
--output DP-3 --mode 1280x800 --scale 1x1 --pos 0x0 --fb 2880x2600 \
--output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --scale 2x2 --pos 0x800
```

or:

```
xrandr \
--output DP-3 --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0 --fb 2880x2600 \
--output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --scale-from 2880x1800 --pos 0x800
```

FrameBuffer size calculation:

```
width = max(1280,1440*2) = 2880
height = 800+900*2 = 2600
```

Results:

- nvidia xrandr scale screenshot

  [image: nvidia xrandr scale screenshot]
- nvidia xrandr scale photo

  [image: nvidia xrandr scale photo]

### Method 2: `nvidia-settings` View Port In/Out

*Note, doesn't work well. `nvidia-settings` does not change frame-buffer to the required size as in `xrandr` command.* It seems a bug (kind of, `nvidia` has its own FB), need more research.

Tried to replicate `xrandr` setup directly using `nvidia-settings` (I used xrandr from method1, marked down nvidia setting, reset settings, then used nvidia-settings directly):

1. `gksu nvidia-settings` → X Server Display Configuration
2. Select external monitor → advanced...
3. Make *ViewPortIn* & *Panning* double of *ViewPortOut* (which is the same as original resolution)
4. Leave internal monitor unchanged then *Apply*

Example:

- [Internal monitor nvidia settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJeC.png)

  ```
  Position:    +0+0
  ViewPortIn:  1280x800
  ViewPortOut: 1280x800+0+0
  Panning:     1280x800
  ```
- [External monitor nvidia settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01eEa.png)

  ```
  Position:    +1280+0 (rightof) or +0+800 (below)
  ViewPortIn:  2880x1800
  ViewPortOut: 1440x900+0+0
  Panning:     2880x1800
  ```

Results: Notice the mouse pointer, it can reach all edges of the 2nd monitor even it only draws  the top left quarter.

- nvidia-settings viewportin screenshot

  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin screenshot]
- nvidia-settings viewportin photo

  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin photo]

**Update:** Well, I could finally get a workaround trick. Add 1px to the width or height of panning (`Panning`)

```
    Panning:     2881x1800 or 2880x1801
```

New Results: I can't explain this, just the background is corrupted if i use below, otherwise every thing seems ok.

- nvidia-settings viewportin with panning trick screenshot

  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin with panning trick screenshot - below]
   <sup>lowered the color quality of above picture to make less then 2MB imgur limit</sup>
  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin with panning trick screenshot - right of]
- nvidia -settings viewportin with panning trick photo

  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin with panning trick photo - below]
  [image: nvidia-settings viewportin with panning trick photo - right of]

### Method 3: `xrandr --output .. --transform "H,0,0,0,V,0,0,0,1"`

*Note, works fine for me, same as method1*

(VGA-0 right of DP-3)

```
xrandr \
--output DP-3  -primary --mode 1280x800 --pos 0x0 --transform "1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1" --fb 4160x1800 \
--output VGA-0 --mode 1440x900 --transform "2,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,1" --right-of DP-3
```

FrameBuffer size calculation:

```
width = 1280+1440*2 = 4160
height = max(800,900*2) = 1800
```

Results:

- nvidia xrandr transform screenshot

  [image: nvidia xrandr transform screenshot]
- nvidia xrandr transform photo

  [image: nvidia xrandr transform photo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer.

Here is  a gist with the requested info : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/233d23a02035085d29944d1a4ba7ecc1

None of your method works, but as I said even a simple `--scale 1x1` causes an error.

Therefore I think it might be a problem with the nvidia drivers (I use the 375)

Therefore I tried with the `nouveau` driver and everything worked. But slowly.

I would really like to be able to use the nvidia drivers so I'll try again with the 340 version tomorrow.

If you have any other idea, please let me know.

Comment: @systho, Could you share the complete `xtrace xrandr...` log and after it run  `grep -i nvidia /var/log/Xorg.0.log`.  Which scaling command did you run exactly, so I can verify with yours ?

Comment: Here are the commands and their results : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d665633ec10e30a7f8adcfa3514f2600

Comment: @systho, your xorg log does list the nvidia mode change events. Anyway, the interesting thing that I could use 1/2 of screen size for  fb, this confirm that we are dealing with at least two frame buffers one controlled xrandr and another one only by nvidia (for real output). So this worked for me, `xrandr --fb 640x400 --output DP-3 --primary --mode 1280x800 --scale 0.5x0.5 --output VGA-0 --off`. Let's break the issue down with only one monitor, logout/login then see with `xtrace xrandr --fb 1920x1080 --output eDP-1-1 --primary --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.5x0.5 --output HDMI-1-1 --off`

Comment: @systho, Could you tell me what exact setup you have tried for nvidia-settings and what did you get an error message? any change of monitors mode even trivial?

Comment: Sorry I have tried too many things to remember exactly what I have done but in the end I'm convinced there is  aproblem with the nvidia driver since even a `1X1` scale causes problems. 

Thank you a lot for your help, you very certainly deserve the bounty.

Comment: @systho, thank you I have made an update for my other linked answer for Nvidia debuging, while I was looking for this issue and some other Nvidia related issues. Also I could find some posts with exact same case error on `--scale` whatever the ratio including `1x1`. If I get my hand on such case, i will try debuging it and report here. Also, if you posted this issue to Nvidia forums, please let me know so I can follow too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution.
I am running Ubuntu 18.04.
This is my xrandr output:

```
light@light:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+3840+92 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 268mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 214mm
   3840x2160     60.02*+  48.02  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
light@light:~$
```

I simply ran the below command and it worked perfectly:

```
light@light:~$ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 2x2 --mode 1920x1080
light@light:~$
```

`--scale 2x2` implies make everything on external screen twice as small.

`--mode` is the resolution you want.

That's it

Comment: That didn't work for me on Ubuntu 18.04 because the mouse boundaries are incorrect - you can't reach some of the screen (also another serious problem that was maybe fixable, but I didn't look further because it was already unusable!).